# Up a docker image by using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yaml file, the following format:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/postgres/my_service/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Which I want to raise using the `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up` and get the following errors:

```
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata': Permission denied
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_multixact': Permission denied
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_multixact/members': Permission denied
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_multixact/members/0000': Permission denied
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_multixact/offsets': Permission denied
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_multixact/offsets/0000': Permission denied
service-postgress  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/pg_wal': Permission denied
```

I tried using different postgresql images, also changed some fields in the file, but it didn't help.
Can you tell me in which direction to think and what you can try to solve the problem.
P.s. with docker-desktop it works fine without any errors, but i cant use it for some reasons.

Comment: OS: macOs Ventura 13.4

Comment: have you changed machine volume from "~/docker/postgres/my_service/data" to another? I think you can meet ownership error cause of default of directory ownership. 
when I set 600 (without executable) I get permission denied error cause It cannot create pgdata directory on It.

Comment: @JeongYoHan i changed the value "~/docker/postgres/my_service/data" but it was with same error but different directory. And I tried to remove this value, same problem.

Comment: even without using host volumes, you get error. then It looks weird. have you tried with postgres tag? `image: postgres:16.0` or `image: postgres:latest`.

Comment: @JeongYoHan not sure, i will check.